# Grabbing the value of checkbox in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Hey so I'm currently a newbie in Vue so have some mercy :)

I am trying to implement a filter bar, where I want to render the checked-box onto a collection view. So a use case would be, if T-shirts was checked then that should render all T-shirts from a DB.

So currently I'm grabbing all the values of beers from my database and rendering that into my filter box:

```
  <div class="overflow menu-list">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="brewery in breweryName">
        <input type="checkbox" name="beer">{{brewery}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Where my Vue instance is defined as so:

```
var filterVM = new Vue({
  el: '#filter-bar',
  data : {
    breweryName : grabFromBeerDB("brewery"),
    beerStyle : grabFromBeerDB("style"),
    checkedBrewery : []
  },
  firebase : {
    beerList: beerDatabaseRef
  }, ...
```

My only question here is how would I reactively grab the values of the boxes that are checked?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `v-model`

```
<input type="checkbox" name="beer" value="A" v-model="checkedBrewery">
<input type="checkbox" name="beer" value="B" v-model="checkedBrewery">
<input type="checkbox" name="beer" value="C" v-model="checkedBrewery">
```

docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: i've tried that, but for some reason when I check on of the boxes, it checks all of them

Comment: @lobcity42 You need to give them a different `value`

Comment: In your case, try this: `<input type="checkbox" name="beer" :value="brewery">`

Answer (score 3):

```
    <li v-for="brewery in breweryName">
        <input type="checkbox" name="beer" :value="brewery" v-model="checkedBrewery">
       {{brewery}}
    </li>
```

The value of input is required, and you must make sure each `value` is different with others.